# ASP.NET User Control Repeater.ItemDataBound Event Not Being Triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, repeater

Event registered in aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="StepRepeater" OnItemDataBound="StepRepeater_ItemDataBound1" runat="server">
```

Tried with AutoEventWireUp true & false

Here's the method in the code behind:

```
    public void LoadSteps(Request request)
    {
        Repeater StepRepeater = new Repeater();

        StepRepeater.DataSource = request.Steps;
        StepRepeater.DataBind();
    }
    protected void StepRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
}
```

When stepping through, it just goes straight through "StepRepeater.DataBind();" without hitting the ItemDataBound event.

Please let me know if any additional information would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OnItemDataBound` value doesn't match your method name.

```
OnItemDataBound="StepRepeater_ItemDataBound1"

protected void StepRepeater_ItemDataBound
```

Remove `1` from the end of `OnItemDataBound` or change your method name.

---

Also as [@Adil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11973242/370103) has stated, remove the `new Repeater()` line:

```
Repeater StepRepeater = new Repeater();
```

---

**UPDATE:** After reading your comment on another answer regarding adding the `new Repeater()` line to prevent a null reference error:

Adding `new Repeater()` is going to create a new instance of a `Repeater` control, therefore **not** referencing the `Repeater` on your ASPX markup file.

If you are receiving a null reference exception, you should check that your `Inherits` property in your `@Page` directive (usually the very top line of your ASPX file) matches the `class` in your `.aspx.cs` file, and that your `CodeFile` property matches your `.aspx.cs` filename.

Comment: It's for this type of scenario that I sometimes prefer to bind my events in the code behind to ensure there's a compilation check to match up my event handlers.

Comment: Sorry, the ItemDataBound1 was just a typo, they match in my code.

Comment: I decided to go a different route, but I'll go back and check this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have `binded` event ItemDataBound to `StepRepeater in html` but you are assigning that datasource of *newly created repeater object* and `no event is attached to this repeater object`.

Remove this statement

```
 Repeater StepRepeater = new Repeater();
```

You code will be

```
public void LoadSteps(Request request)
{
    StepRepeater.DataSource = request.Steps;
    StepRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Change the name of `OnItemDataBound` event in html to match the code behind

```
<asp:Repeater ID="StepRepeater" OnItemDataBound="StepRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
```

Comment: I had to add the "new repeater" to avoid a null reference error. Is there a different way to do this? It won't run, as of now, with the the "new repeater"

Comment: You will not have null reference as you have StepRepeater in your html. I have Updated my answer.

Comment: It still gives me a null reference error. This was my initial issue, and it is why I added the "new" reference.